# Reference on instantons in gauge theories

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, gauge-theory, instantons

Is there a  reasonably detailed and systematic exposition of the theory of instantons in non-abelian gauge theories?

Comment: Coleman's Aspects of Symmetry and Shifman's Advanced QFT.

Comment: @Avantgarde : Coleman is not detailed enough for me. I will have a look at Shifman’s book. Thank you.

Comment: I would say, probably the most complete reference is the [Manton-Sutcliffe](http://www.lmpt.univ-tours.fr/~volkov/Manton-Sutcliffe.pdf).

Comment: http://inspirehep.net/record/165126?ln=en