# Instantons in mathematical physics

Tags: mathematical-physics, resource-recommendations, instantons

I am extremely curious about instantons in the context of mathematical physics, and I would like to learn more about the subject. Could anyone give me good references about this? Especially references of modern research articles.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/471155/2451

Answer (score 2):

It's not modern, but Coleman's "Uses of Instantons" is a great introduction. Google the title to find free-online versions.

Comment: Thank you! I already have some knowledge about instantons. Coleman goes in detail but it's more theoretical physics than mathematics. Do you have any reference in modern literature too? That would be great, thank you anyways and best regards.

Comment: Modern *mathematical* work on instantons involves situations where they give exact answers.  This oinvolves the localization condition of the Duistermaat-Heckman theorem and equivariant co-homology. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duistermaat-Heckman_formula

Comment: Thanks dear @mike stone. Any suggested authors or references?

All the best.